# Windows Phone store app have link, but can't be found

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Few days ago i'm upload my app in th store. Everything worked fine,I got the message the app was accepted. Yesterday I got the working URL for Windows 10 && URL for Windows Phone 8.1 and earlier (before 404 page not found). But still can't found my app in the store.

The other strange part was, that I can't found my another app in the store (just disappeared). Another app was found on the first day after appearance in store.

ps: status - in the store
pss: sorry, bad english

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general microsoft tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait few more days .. the MS store was acting a bit funny in the past few days, the download stats were not up-to-date ...if it still does not appear, contact MS support